# How can i set a crontab to execute a mysql query and log the output?

Tags: mysql, cron

Well, title self describes it..
I need to run a sql function to clean some duplicated posts, i need to do it several times a day so i need to use cron...

I set a new crontab job, like this:

```
00 16,18,19,20,21 * * * mysql -h MY-DB-HOST.COM -u MY-DB-USERNAME -pMY-DB-PASSWORD -e "delete from hotaru_posts where post_id in ( select post_id from ( select post_id from hotaru_posts a group by post_title having count(post_title) > 1 ) b )" >> /tmp/cron_job.log
```

but nothing seems to be logged, so i supposed its not working.

Theres no problem with the sql sentence, thats not the issue here.

Anything wrong with my cron rule?

Comment: Does your username/password contain symbols that might confuse bash? Like `&`?

Comment: First thought, check /var/log/cron to make sure it's even attempting to run.

Comment: Second thought, use full path to mysql in case it's not in PATH.

Comment: Is /tmp/cron_job.log set to world write permissions?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, it uses only numbers, letters and underscore.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, i dont think i have access to that path.

Comment: @Umbrella, the tmp/ dir is set to 770, the cron_job.log was 644, i changed to 777, the cron will execute again in 40 mins, so lets see if that was the problem.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, what you mean by "full path to mysql"?

Comment: I mean use /usr/local/bin/mysql instead of just mysql. (Or whatever your path actually is.)

Comment: Lucas, if you are still having this problem, I would try two things -- first, change '00' to '0'. I doubt that will fix it, but you never know. Second, just try running "echo 'test' >> /tmp/cron_job.log" instead of your mysql command to make sure cron is working at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well, since the mysql was not working properly directly inside crontab (thought that i think that was a path issue like Alex Howansky said), i created a php file dealing this query and called the php in crontab, much easier, and give me the option to use conditions.

the cron job:

```
00 8,14,18,19,20,21,23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/aikaforum/cata/public_html/cron_dup.php >> /cata/tmp/cron_dup.log
```

the php:

```
<?php
$username="xxxxxxx";
$password="xxxxxx";
$dbname="xxxxxx";
$dbhost="xxxxx.xxxxx.com";
$query="delete from hotaru_posts where post_id in ( select post_id from ( select post_id from hotaru_posts a group by post_title having count(post_title) > 1 ) b )";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(strftime('%c')." Unable to select database");
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
echo strftime('%c')." ok!";
?>
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Nice alternative! Secure file with 400 permissions, so that only the owner of the file can read these clear text passwords.

Answer (score 4):

execute the following in your cron configurations

```
echo "your_SQL_statement" | mysql --skip-column-names -udbuser -pdbpassword yourdb >> yourlog.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your script is working but isn't actually returning any output. Here's my local test:

```
 mysql -u username dbname -e "delete from posts" > foo             
 cat foo
 (empty file)
```

Just to be clear, foo is an empty file. `posts` was not an empty table.

So, just to be more precise, I think that's the expected behavior of MySQL here, although I can't confirm this in their docs. If you want/need output here, you'll probably need to write a script to check your table before/after deleting.

Comment: whats the difference between > and >> ??

Comment: Sorry, that's the formatting from my command prompt, I just removed it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I removed something else. '>' writes to a file, but overwrites any existing content. '>>' appends to a file, preserving the existing content.

Comment: well, it was suposed to run at 16:00, its already 16:15 and the log is empty and the duplicated posts still there.. So, it is realy not working, its not only about the output. =(

Comment: Then you probably have a problem with your cron setup. You should try what some of the other commenters have suggested -- make sure that cron is running, see if there is any helpful output in the cron log itself, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the full path to scripts executed by a cronjob. For instance if the mysql binary's location is **/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql** you'd use that in your cronjob.

```
00 16,18,19,20,21 * * * /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h MY-DB-HOST.COM -u .....
```

Comment: As an alternative to calling with full path, you can modify the PATH variable in crontab (which by default is only `/usr/bin:/bin`). Like: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`