# Executing MySQL Scheduled?

Tags: php, mysql, events, sql-update, dreamhost

I'm using DreamHost as the server for my website, and I'm trying to execute a certain MySQL query every day, week, and month to change the database for my website. I started out using the event scheduler on my local host, then I found out I'm not able to use it on DreamHost because I don't have the "super" privileges for it.

Anyways, my question is, is there a way to execute a query such as:

> UPDATE table 
>   SET field1 = field2, field2 = 0

every day, week, and month at midnight? Or is there a way to execute a PHP script at a certain time with that MySQL in it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does your hosting provider allow you to set up cron jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamhost allows for cronjobs ; see http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Crontab for some useage examples.

See also [How can i set a crontab to execute a mysql query and log the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948220/how-can-i-set-a-crontab-to-execute-a-mysql-query-and-log-the-output) for more detailed information.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'd heard of them but I knew nothing about them.