# Use cronjob to update stock status in OpenCart

Tags: cron, opencart

I am planning to set up a cronjob to update all zero products (quantity = 0) status to disabled (0).

Where would you recommend to put this script - under admin or in the root?

Any dangers with this kind of script?

===========================================================

This is the SQL I am trying to make work:

```
UPDATE product p
SET p.status = 0
FROM product_to_store p2s, product p
WHERE p2s.product_id = p.product_id AND p.quantity=0 AND p.status=1 AND p2s.store_id=0
```

But I get an error with this one.

SOLUTION!!!

```
UPDATE product p 
JOIN product_to_store p2s ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id
SET p.status=0
WHERE p2s.store_id=0 AND p.quantity=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to implement this correctly, then you will need to create this on the `catalog` side. I'd recommend using a vQmod to add a cron function, with a key check to ensure nobody is running the code. For example, adding this to your `/catalog/controller/common/home.php`

```
public function cron() {
    if(empty($this->request->get['key']) || $this->request->get['key'] != 'Your-Key-Here') die('ERROR');

    // Run SQL update code
    $this->db->query("
        UPDATE
            `" . DB_PREFIX . "product`
        SET
            `status` = IF( `quantity` < 1, 0, 1)
    ");
}
```

Then you would call `http://yoursite.com/?route=common/home/cron&key=Your-Key-Here` to run the code

Comment: Jay - thx for the tip! It looks to be a good idea.

I have added the SQL statement I am planning to run but I can't get it to work. Any idea how to get it going?

Comment: Do I need to add model-file or can I write the SQL directly in the home.php code?

Comment: @HansLernestål - If you want to do it properly,  you should be using the `DB_PREFIX` variable and using the database object. You also shouldn't need to use the store table and any joins. See above edit which will enable and disable products based on their quantity values

Comment: Jay - thx. I will try this, but will the update be on products that are assigned to store_id = 0 and have quantity = 0 only?

Comment: @HansLernestål - No it will apply to all stores, though I'm not sure why you would want it to only happen on the default store?

Comment: Jay - I have an auction module and run that on a second store (store_id=2). When a product is added to the auction module the quantity is set to zero until the auction is finished. Hence, if I give ALL products with quantity zero a disabled status the auction products will not show.

Also, the link you suggested above does not work with the script in home.php

Comment: Tested this locally and works fine. If you're wanting to use just a simple cron and sql query you might want to use this instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948220/how-can-i-set-a-crontab-to-execute-a-mysql-query-and-log-the-output

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file where ever you want, as long as cron has permissions to access the directory. It won't make a difference where to store it. I would always recommend to run some tests with such kind of scripts, but if you code it correctly, there shouldn't be any bad side effects.

I personally think it makes sense to store files runned by cron in a separate folder in order to find them easier later and because you can set ownership to cron for this folder. (but that's more opinion-based).