# Cron Job in Cpanel with PHP

Tags: php, cron

I have two mysqli query which I want run on different time. I have read how can I do it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9981741/7445724)

But I want only run if admin have set it automated from checkbox value. Anyone can please suggest me how can I do it in cpanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save the check box information of admin user in your server such as mysql.

And Then, you can try to implement that the file what will be excuted by crontab checkes this admin value.

Following to that value, you can finish directly or continue.

Answer (score 1):

You should to create file that checks the value of checkbox. if true- run the script, else- do nothing. The cron jobs should run this code.